# Image not updating without refresh after upload, using PHP and ajaxform

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, parse-platform, ajaxform

My problem is that I upload an image, which works without leaving the page, and it is all successful. In the success callback of the ajaxForm plugin, I'm changing the src of the image, but it doesn't update. But I know the image has finished uploading when the success callback is reached. I'm even requerying for it.

Still, I have to reload the page in order to see it. It worked perfectly when I was using pure JS and no PHP. I've tried a lot of different rearranging but still nothing. I've tried using the attr function to change the src, but I still have to reload. The image src is correctly changed according to the page source.

Can anyone help? Why am I still having to reload the page?

My upload form:

```
f($whoseprofile == $currentUser->get("username"))
        {
echo '<form id = "upform" action="/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><label for="uploadpicture"><img class="overlayImage" src="/img/newplus.png"><input type="file" id="uploadpicture" name="picture" /></label></form>';

        }
```

Next is the ajaxForm.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#uploadpicture').change(function() {

                $('#upform').ajaxForm({

                    beforeSubmit: function() {

                    },
                    success: function() { 
                        <? php $query = ParseUser::query();
                        $query - > equalTo("username", $whoseprofile);
                        $results = $query - > find();
                        $picurl = $results[0] - > get("profilePicture") - > getUrl(); ?>
                        $('#profilepic').html("");
                        $('#profilepic').html("<img id='profilepic' class='profilepic' src='<?php echo $picurl;?>'>");
                    }
                }).submit();




            });

        });
    </script>
```

Here is upload.php

```
    <?php 

require 'autoload.php';

$app_id = ;
$rest_key = ;
$master_key = ;

use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;
use Parse\ParseRelation;
use Parse\ParseSessionStorage;

session_start();
ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );

$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();

if ($currentUser) {

 $file = ParseFile::createFromData( file_get_contents( $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'] ), $_FILES['picture']['name'] );
  $file->save();

$currentUser->set("profilePicture", $file);
$currentUser->save();


} else {

header("Location: blahlblahblah");
exit();

}

?>
```

Comment: you have php-code in your ajaxForm-script, so this is not the script interpreted by your browser and the php-code will not beupdated because it will be nterpreted befor the browser will see the script, please post the final script interpreted by the browser.

Comment: Ah, they do match in the actual code. They're both supposed to be "up".  I changed it just for this post to be clearer.

Comment: There's this that's questionable `<? php $query = ParseUser::query();` and `- >` not sure about the `- >` but it's just bad form.

Comment: That's because I'm using Parse.com as a database. That's how their PHP code is written. (https://parse.com/docs/php_guide)

Comment: I changed them to match. It was a mistake. And the -> is nothing I can change. That is the syntax for the Parse PHP sdk.

Comment: That JS looks to be jQuery. Silly question but I'll ask it anyway. Is the jQuery library loaded? Plus these `$app_id = ;
$rest_key = ;
$master_key = ;` that will/should create a parse error. I.e.: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in...`

Comment: It is jQuery, and the jQuery sure is loaded. Not a silly question since I still have a lot to learn and am definitely prone to silly mistakes. Literally everything seems to work as it should except that the image isn't refreshing.

Comment: Those will only create a Parse error if they're blank. Of course I wasn't going to actually post my keys on here. Already accidentally did that once, hah.

Comment: Well I know that lol it's just that I take posted code literally. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: I appreciate the help and time more than you know. Didn't see your updated comment until now. Anyways, I've come to the conclusion that the file hasn't actually been saved when the success callback is...well, called on. It turns out that any other image from the internet will work, which is why I've come to that conclusion. This is why I have to reload. But at the same time PHP is not asynchronous, so it confuses me that the file isn't saved when it gets to the success callback.